# How do I send an event from the browser to the server using grails

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, grails

I am trying to use grails-2.3.5 and the grails events push plugin:

https://github.com/smaldini/grails-events-push

to send events back and forth between the server and the client. So far, I've managed to send events from the server to the client, and from the server to the server. But I cannot seem to get the client to successfully send an event to the server.

In my BuildConf.groovy I've added:

```
mavenRepo "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
```

and

```
compile ":events-push:1.0.M7"
```

and I've changed the version of the tomcat plugin from 7.0.50 to 7.0.42 as described at:

https://github.com/smaldini/grails-events-push/issues/55

My event receiving service looks like:

```
package sandbox

import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Transactional
class MyService {
    @grails.events.Listener
    def bagsUpdated(Map data) {
        System.out.println("Event fired")
    }
}
```

and in my .gsp file I load the javascript with:

```
<r:require module="grailsEvents"/>
```

and try to fire the event using:

```
<button onclick="grailsEvents.send('bagsUpdated', null);">Click Me</button>
```

Anyway, each button click gets me the following message on the grails console:

```
| Error 2014-02-11 07:18:16,982 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR http11.Http11Protocol  - Error reading request, ignored
Message: null
    Line | Method
->>  339 | invokeWebSocketProtocol in org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     83 | onTextData              in org.atmosphere.container.TomcatWebSocketHandler
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                     in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

and my javascript console error looks like:

```
08:00:13.618 The connection to ws://localhost:8080/sandbox/g-eventsbus/eventsbus?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=1.1.0.beta3&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&X-Cache-Date=0&topics=eventsbus%2CbagsUpdated was interrupted while the page was loading. jquery.atmosphere.js:839
08:00:13.618 "Websocket closed, reason: Connection was closed abnormally (that is, with no close frame being sent)." jquery.atmosphere.js:2436
08:00:13.618 "Websocket closed, wasClean: false" jquery.atmosphere.js:2436
```